# Best way to run a never ending service in Android

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I have a service that gives a notification if user has changed his location. I want this service to keep on running until user explicitly force stops my application in application manager. I have used following method:

```
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, LocationService2.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent1, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),2*60000, contentIntent);
```

Service class:

```
public class LocationService2 extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v("TAG", "STARTLS");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");

    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    // Use this location to give notification if required.
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
}
```

This method does not work on all phones.
Is AlarmManager the best way to do this. If yes, then how can I improve this code to work on all phones?

Comment: can you post your service class

Answer (score 3):

You should make your service a `Foreground Service`. You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/).

Answer (score 1):

**Manifest Entry**

```
<receiver android:name="YourPackagename.RestartReceiver">
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name="YourPackagename.AlarmReceiver" >
</receiver>
```

On phone reboot need to reinitialize alarm manager 
**RestartReceiver.java**

```
public class RestartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intentReciever = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentReciever, 0);
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis() + GlobalContext.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL),
                    GlobalContext.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL, alarmIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //you can put your logic over here
    }
}
```

Put below code in your Splash Screen

```
private void initService() {
        if(!app_preferences.getBoolean("isServiceRunning", false))
        {
            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intentReciever = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LoadingScreen.this, 0, intentReciever, 0);
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis()+GlobalContext.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL),
                    GlobalContext.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL, alarmIntent);
            app_preferences.edit().putBoolean("isServiceRunning", true).commit();
        }
    }
```

//Note: its not good way to check your Alerm service using shared preference is running or not.

Comment: I have already taken care of bootcomlete reciever but in my case problem is that service stops running even after user removes the app from app switcher in some phones.

Comment: I have posted my service class. As you can see I am returning 'START_STICKY' in onStartCommand.

Comment: Service still stops after four or five hours

Comment: @RuchirBaronia please check https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Answer (score 0):

The steps to make a never ending service are :

```
1.) Start service using alarmManager.
2.) Check in onResume if service is running & restart if not.
3.) Return START_STICKY from onStartCommand().
4.) In OnStartCommand() , create a thread and do the needful from that thread .All the logical stuff should be there in while(true).
```

This way your service will never be killed .

Answer (score 0):

In given code i have put some good things like you can **[communicate with activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)** using [binder service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) via listner. You can notify your activity that you lost internet connction by writing code in service...

Create **[service as sticky](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)** which will never end. if user will kill app it will again automatically restart.

When compare to alarm manager you may face duplication/multiple service get started. like we need to identify and prevent that if Alarm manager already i have created then don't start again as per my another answer written in same question.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver"><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/></intent-filter></receiver>
<service android:name=".MyService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

        CommunicationListner listener;
        public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
            public MyService getService() {
                // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
                return MyService.this;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return mBinder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(internetConnectionReceiver);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            registerReceiver(internetConnectionReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        //communication with activity
        public void registerChatReceivedListener(CommunicationListner listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public void removeChatReceivedListener() {
            chatListener = null;
        }


        private BroadcastReceiver internetConnectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            }
        };

        public MyService() {
        }

    }
```

To restart your service on restart phone
**BootCompleteReceiver.Java**

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Put code in you splash screen to start myservice if its already started then also no need to worry.

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Start the service anytime it got killed.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    startService(new Intent(this, LocationService2.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions in android 5 and higher is using AlarmManger and Broadcast Receiver